# RSpec - Identical strings failing comparison

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I am running a test on the output of an XML parser I wrote in Rails. When I run RSpec it fails and shows me what it 'expected' and what it 'got' and their contents at least are identical.

I've tried using eq, eql, equal and match but none have worked.

The test:

```
expect(sql).to eql("INSERT INTO users (id, first_name, last_name, city, street_address, country, postcode, company, email, username, phone_number, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (1, 'Dewayne', 'Dare', 'Rippinfort', '1171 Lucas Place', 'Malaysia', '94876-5561', 'Kiehn LLC', 'turner@schmidt.biz', 'kay_armstrong', '652.488.7428', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);\n")
```

The part of the parser that creates the output:

```
@sql << "INSERT INTO users (id, first_name, last_name, city, street_address, country, postcode, company, email, username, phone_number, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (" +
  "#{self.last_user[:id]}, " +
  "'#{clean(self.last_user[:first_name])}', " +
  "'#{clean(self.last_user[:last_name])}', " +
  "'#{clean(self.last_user[:city])}', " +
  "'#{clean(self.last_user[:street_address])}', " +
  "'#{clean(self.last_user[:country])}', " +
  "'#{clean(self.last_user[:postcode])}', " +
  "'#{clean(self.last_user[:company])}', " +
  "'#{clean(self.last_user[:email])}', " +
  "'#{clean(self.last_user[:username])}', " +
  "'#{clean(self.last_user[:phone_number])}', " + 
  "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, " +
  "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" +
");\n"
```

The failed test:

```
  1) UserImporter with real data creates an SQL file ready to import the article
 Failure/Error: expect(sql).to eql("INSERT INTO users (id, first_name, last_name, city, street_address, country, postcode, company, email, username, phone_number, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (1, 'Dewayne', 'Dare', 'Rippinfort', '1171 Lucas Place', 'Malaysia', '94876-5561', 'Kiehn LLC', 'turner@schmidt.biz', 'kay_armstrong', '652.488.7428', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);\n")

   expected: "INSERT INTO users (id, first_name, last_name, city, street_address, country, postcode, company, emai...C', 'turner@schmidt.biz', 'kay_armstrong', '652.488.7428', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);\n"
        got: "INSERT INTO users (id, first_name, last_name, city, street_address, country, postcode, company, emai...C', 'turner@schmidt.biz', 'kay_armstrong', '652.488.7428', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);\n"

   (compared using eql?)

   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,3 @@
    INSERT INTO users (id, first_name, last_name, city, street_address, country, postcode, company, email, username, phone_number, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (1, 'Dewayne', 'Dare', 'Rippinfort', '1171 Lucas Place', 'Malaysia', '94876-5561', 'Kiehn LLC', 'turner@schmidt.biz', 'kay_armstrong', '652.488.7428', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
   +INSERT INTO users (id, first_name, last_name, city, street_address, country, postcode, company, email, username, phone_number, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (1, 'Dewayne', 'Dare', 'Rippinfort', '1171 Lucas Place', 'Malaysia', '94876-5561', 'Kiehn LLC', 'turner@schmidt.biz', 'kay_armstrong', '652.488.7428', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: Is it possible that the strings have a different encoding? For example one might be UTF-8 and the other ASCII. You can check that by calling `encoding` on both strings and compare the returned value.

Comment: The diff output says that in the new file(+), starting at line 1, there are 3 lines, while in the old file(-), starting at line 1, there are 2 lines, where the expected is the old file, and the actual is the new file.  There's probably a blank line after the got: line (see the blank line before `(compared using eql?)`?

Comment: @7stud thanks, your comment helped me figure it out, I wasn't aware of the meaning of those numbers. Unfortunately it was a dumb mistake in my code that was printing the line out twice so nothing interesting to note on my end! Cheers

Comment: @DannySantos can you answer your own question? Thanks!

Comment: *my code that was printing the line out twice*-- Ack!  The diff output actually tells you that: You see the two INSERT lines after the `@@...@@`?  The first one starts with a space(i.e. not a `-` or a `+`).  That means the line is common to both files.  The next line starts with a `+`.  That means the new file has that additional line, i.e. the new file has two INSERT lines while the old file has one INSERT line.  And, as stated before the new file is the actual, and the old file is the expected.  (If a line starts with a `-`, then the old file has that line, but the new file does not.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that my code was printing the line out twice. I spotted the mistake thanks to the 7stud:

> You see the two INSERT lines after the @@...@@? The first one starts with a space(i.e. not a - or a +). That means the line is common to both files. The next line starts with a +. That means the new file has that additional line, i.e. the new file has two INSERT lines while the old file has one INSERT line. And, as stated before the new file is the actual, and the old file is the expected. (If a line starts with a -, then the old file has that line, but the new file does not.)